# Is there an S4 equivalent to unlist()?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have some experience working with `S4` objects and their slots, so I know how to access specific slots and sub-slots.  What I'd like to learn is how to "de-slotify" an object in the way that `unlist` takes apart an `S3` list.
My immediate goal is to have an S4 counterpart to one of my toys which returns the number of elements of an object:

```
lssize<-function(items){
            if (any(sapply(sapply(items,get),typeof)=='closure')){
        warning('Closures in list, will ignore.')
        items<-items[(sapply(sapply(bar,get),typeof)=='closure')!=TRUE]
    }
    sizes<-sapply(sapply(sapply(sapply(items,get,simplify=F), unlist,simplify=F), as.vector,simplify=F), length)
    return(sizes)
    }
```

(no fair laughing at my code :-) ).  I am hoping not to have to write some recursion routine which extracts slots one at a time to convert them.

Edit:  I know `object.size` will return the bytecount; not what I'm after here.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `str()` (`utils:::str.default` really) --
both its results when applied to S4 objects, and the code it uses to walk through all of an S4 object's slots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This is revised to be closer to a previous, deleted answer, using `slotName` and `slot` rather than relying on `attributes`). We could write a function that tests whether an instance is an S4 object, and if so extracts all the slots as a list and recurses

```
f = function(x) {
    if (isS4(x)) {
        nms <- slotNames(x)
        names(nms) <- nms
        lapply(lapply(nms, slot, object=x), f)
    } else x
}
```

and then

```
A = setClass("A", representation(x="numeric"))
B = setClass("B", representation(a="A", b="numeric"))
f(B())
```

to arrive at a plain old list that we could use for whatever purposes we want.

```
$a
$a$x
numeric(0)

$a$class
[1] "A"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"


$b
numeric(0)

$class
[1] "B"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
```

`f` might need to be enhanced, e.g., to handle NULL values or S4 classes made from S3 classes via `setOldClass`. The code to `validObject` would be my choice of places to look for a more comprehensive traversal.

A generalization might make a visitor, along the lines of

```
visitLeavesWith <-
    function(object, FUN, ...)
{
    f = function(x) {
        if (isS4(x)) {
            slots <- setNames(slotNames(x), slotNames(x))
            lapply(lapply(slots, slot, object=x), f)
        } else FUN(x, ...)
    }
    f(object)
}
```

e.g.,

```
visitLeavesWith(B(), length)
```

Comment: This looks nice -- a good enhancement of the (removed) other answer.  Yeah, I probably should "convert" to reporting sizes of objects in bytes rather than element counts anyway :-)

Comment: I only get to upvote you once :-) .  Thanks for taking the time to spiffify your code. I'll give you full credit when (if) I build a package of helper tools which include `lssize` .

Comment: BTW, so I credit the right guy -- are you the fellow who works at Fred H.  ?

Comment: A thought rather later on: for my "get the length" function, I need to make that `else FUN(x,...)` be `else length(unlist(x))` to cover the possibility of a list object. Obvious in hindsight :-)